# Change of variable paradox

Tags: integration, change-of-variable

Below is very normal steps of getting the area formula of circle using integration and change of varible.  But there seems to be a paradox.
Let $x=a\sin\theta$ and $dx=a\cos\theta{d\theta}$
$$\begin{align}{}
A &=4\int^a_0\sqrt{a^2-x^2}dx &(1)\\
  &=4\int^a_0\sqrt{a^2-a^2\sin^2\theta}dx &(2)\\
  &=4a\int^a_0\sqrt{1-\sin^2\theta}dx &(3)\\
  &=4a\int^a_0\cos\theta{dx} &(4)\\
  &=4a^2\int^{\pi/2}_0\cos^2\theta{d\theta} 
  \enspace\text{whereas }x=a\to\theta=\pi/2 \text{ and } x=0\to\theta=0       &(5)\\
  &=2a^2\int^{\pi/2}_01+\cos2\theta{d\theta} &(6)\\
  &=2a^2\Big[\theta+\frac{1}{2}\sin{2\theta}\Big]^{\pi/2}_0 &(7)\\
  &=\pi{a^2} &(8)
\end{align}$$
Now comes my questions: For step (5), it is also true that $x=0\to\theta=\pi$, if we substitue this to the lower limit, we get $$A=2a^2\Big[\theta+\frac{1}{2}\sin{2\theta}\Big]^{\pi/2}_\pi=-\pi{a^2}$$ this seems like a paradox, what went wrong?

Another paradox is that for the same step (5), it is also true that $x=a\to\theta=\frac{5\pi}{2}$, if we substitute this to the upper limit, we get$$A=2a^2\Big[\theta+\frac{1}{2}\sin{2\theta}\Big]^{{5\pi}/{2}}_0=5\pi{a^2}$$ This paradox is slightly different than the above paradox which might be explained by that the range of $x$ is $[-a,a]$ instead of$[0,a]$when $\theta$ is in $[0,(5\pi)/2]$. But I hope there is a more rigorous explanation for both paradoxes.

Comment: When you let $x=a\sin(\theta)$, you are typically letting $\arcsin(x/a) = \theta$ which is bounded between $-\pi/2$ and $\pi/2$ (both included). If you let $\theta = \pi$, you would have a wrong answer. The same kind of argument goes for your second "paradox."

Comment: $\sqrt {x^2} = |x|$ as the output of the radical is always positive. 
 This is also a way of defining the absolute value operation. 
 So, $\sqrt{1-\sin^2 \theta} = |\cos \theta|.$  We usually don't bother with the absolute value brackets because we choose limits of integration such that $\cos \theta \ge 0.$   However, if we are going to be precise, they really should be there.  Once we account for that your paradox resolves itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You really need to track carefully what's going on with the substitution.

Say we have a substitution: $f(\theta)=x$, where $x\in [x_1, x_2], \theta\in [\theta_1, \theta_2]$, *usually* we need $f(\theta)$ to be increasing and $f(\theta_1)=x_1, f(\theta_2)=x_2$, and of course we need $f$ to be (continuously) differentiable over $[\theta_1, \theta_2]$. However, it's not strictly required that $x_1<x_2$ and $\theta_1<\theta_2$ hold and even when $f$ is not monotone, it's possible for the substitution to work, but one has to be careful.

For example, we may have $\theta$ from $\pi$ to $\pi/2$ to represent the process of $x$ varying from $0$ to $a$. However, you need to keep track of all the computations. As if so, we have $\sqrt{1-\sin^2(\theta)}=-\cos(\theta)\not=\cos(\theta)$! since $\cos(\theta)\le 0$. With the extra negative sign, the first "paradox" is resolved.

The second paradox suffered the same issue, as for certain values of $\theta$ in $[0, 5\pi/2]$, you picked the wrong square-root. If $\theta$ goes from $0$ to $5\pi/2$, then $f(\theta)=a\sin(\theta)$ doesn't simply go from $0$ to $a$, but winds around more than once, it actaully goes from $0$ to $a$, then $a$ to $0$, then $0$ to $a$, etc. This is no big deal, as there ought to be cancellation of integrals (the integral for $x$ from $0$ to $a$ should cancel the one from $a$ to $0$), but only when all the imtermediate steps are properly handled.

Anyway, it's not a good idea to do (definite) integrals for $f$ that is not monotone.